# Bootstrap Modal issue with fileinput

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a real interesting problem with a bootstrap modal, let's start from beginning.

I have a list of inventories - with the function that you can book, edit, view, and delete. See image

[image]

All my functions works except edit, the problem I have with edit is that I can only edit one item before a page refresh. If I click edit on the first row that image shown is used on any subsequent edit I do - if I click the 2 or 3 row edit I get the first image - see popup image

[image]

This is the javascript to call the modal to pop up, as you can see I'm clearing the form first - making an Ajax call to get the data for that button. I only have a problem with an image not being able to show the actual image for an item.

```
//
//  Edit the inventory
//

function edit_inventory(id)
{
   save_method = 'update';
   $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
   $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
   $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
   $('[name="image_name]').empty();

   //Ajax Load data from ajax
   $.ajax({
      url : "<?php echo site_url('warehouse/inventory/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data)
      {
        var previewimage =  data.image_name;
        $('[name="image_name]').val(data.image_name);
        $('[name="id"]').val(data.id);
        $('[name="user_id"]').val(data.user_id);
        $('[name="name"]').val(data.name);
        $('[name="description"]').val(data.description);
        $('[name="type_id"]').val(data.type_id);
        $('[name="certifications_id"]').val(data.certifications_id);
        $('[name="condition_id"]').val(data.condition_id);
        $('[name="location_id"]').val(data.location_id);
        $('[name="location_in_warehouse"]').val(data.location_in_warehouse);
        $('[name="quantity_id"]').val(data.quantity_id);
        $('[name="size_id"]').val(data.size_id);
        $('[name="skills_required_id"]').val(data.skills_required_id);
        $('[name="use_id"]').val(data.use_id);
        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
        $('.modal-title').text('Edit Inventory'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

        $("#image_name").fileinput({
            uploadUrl: "<?php echo site_url('warehouse/inventory/ajax_fileupload')?>",
            deleteUrl: "<?php echo site_url('warehouse/inventory/ajax_deletefile')?>",
            showUpload: true,
            uploadAsync: true,
            // your upload server url
            allowedFileExtensions : ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png','gif'],
            overwriteInitial: false,
            maxFileSize: 1000,
            minFileCount: 1,
            maxFileCount: 5,
            maxFilesNum: 10,
            initialPreview: [
            // IMAGE DATA
                "<?php echo site_url('assets/uploads/')?>/" + previewimage,
            ],
            initialPreviewAsData: true, // identify if you are sending preview data only and not the raw markup
            initialPreviewFileType: 'image', // image is the default and can be overridden in config below
            initialPreviewConfig: [
                {caption: previewimage, size: 576237, width: "120px", url: "warehouse/inventory/ajax_fileupload", key: 1},
            ],

            layoutTemplates: {
                main1: "{preview}\n" +
                "<div class=\'input-group {class}\'>\n" +
                "   <div class=\'input-group-btn\'>\n" +
                "       {browse}\n" +
                "       {upload}\n" +
                "       {remove}\n" +
                "   </div>\n" +
                "   {caption}\n" +
                "</div>"
            }
        }); 

     },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }
  });   
}
```

For each item that I select to edit, I'm calling the backend to get the latest image from the database, each time a new image name is set in

```
var previewimage =  data.image_name;
```

For the file input, I'm using the krajee bootstrap fileinput library, as I need to upload images. http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo

You would expect by adding the new previewimage variable to the

```
        initialPreview: [
        // IMAGE DATA
            "<?php echo site_url('assets/uploads/')?>/" + previewimage,
        ],
```

It would show a different image - somehow the first edit click done that image resides in the modal and is not cleared.

I have tried several things to clear the modal e.g.

```
     $('#image_name').val('');

    $('form').find('input[type=file]').val('');
```

Nothing works, it seems that I'm not getting the right element to clear or there is something in the krajee bootstrap file input that is not cleared correctly.

This is the code for my modal

```
<!-- Bootstrap modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Inventory Form</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body form">
            <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/>

                <div class="form-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Select File</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input id="image_name" name="image_name[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>                       
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="name" placeholder="Item Name" class="form-control" type="text" data-validate="true" data-error="Required Field" required>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Description</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="description" placeholder="Give a Description" class="form-control" type="text" data-validate="true"  data-error="Required Field" required>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Location in Warehouse</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="location_in_warehouse" placeholder="Give details on were to find in Warehouse" class="form-control" type="text" data-validate="true" data-error="Required Field" required>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Type</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select id="types" name="type_id" class="form-control">
                            </select>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Usage</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select id="usages" name="use_id" class="form-control">
                            </select>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Skills Required</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select id="skills" name="skills_required_id" class="form-control">
                            </select>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Certifications</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select id="certificates" name="certifications_id" class="form-control">
                            </select>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Location</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select id="locations" name="location_id" class="form-control">
                            </select>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Quantity</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="quantity_id" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control" type="number" data-validate="true" data-error="Only numbers allowed" required>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Condition</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select id="conditions" name="condition_id" class="form-control">
                            </select>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Item Size</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="size_id" placeholder="Enter a size of the item" class="form-control" type="text">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

     </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I appreciate any help or suggestion to resolve this issue.

---

Here is the server side code:

```
switch ($inventory->status) {
  case '0':
    $row[] = '<img alt="sign in" src="' . base_url() . 'assets/uploads/warehousein.png">';
    $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Book" onclick="book_inventory('."'".$inventory->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> Book</a>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_inventory('."'".$inventory->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="javascript:void(0)" title="View" onclick="view_inventory('."'".$inventory->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> View</a>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="delete" onclick="delete_inventory('."'".$inventory->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';
  break;
```

As you can see, I add the `inventory->id` to the button.

Comment: Add the edit button code as well, are you passing the correct `id` to `edit_inventory(id)`

Comment: The edit button is served from the server through this AJAX response. The edit_inventory(id) is correct as all the other data for edit is correct, it is just the image that keeps the first image shown when an edit button is clicked.

Comment: try like this $('.file-loading').val('');

Answer (score 1):

just put this code first before you declare file input

```
$('#selector').fileinput('destroy');
```